# can a Banach space admit a subsymmetric basis AND a symmetric basis?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, schauder-basis

**Definitions.**  A (Schauder) basis for a Banach space is called *symmetric* if it is unconditional and uniformly equivalent to all its permutations. It is called *subsymmetric* if it is unconditional and uniformly equivalent to all its subsequences.  A generous introduction to symmetric and subsymmetric bases can be found in chapter 3 of the Lindenstrauss-Tzafriri book *Classical Banach Spaces I*.

**Question 1.** Does there exist a Banach space admitting a basis which is symmetric and another basis which is subsymmetric but not symmetric?

**Question 2.**  Do we know an example of a Banach space which admits a subsymmetric basis but not a symmetric one?

**Question 3.**  Do we know an example of a Banach space which admits a *unique* subsymmetric basis (up to equivalence) but not a symmetric one?

**Discussion.**  I have actually already answered questions #2 and 3 in the affirmative, but I am wondering if this is already known.  I do not have an answer for #1.